# ContentEditable section posting to PHP

Tags: php, html, contenteditable

I am working on a project where I need to use a section where the content editable is set to true.

The data within the section needs to be posted to PHP. What I am doing is when the user presses submit instead of it posting, it will instead call a javascript function to perform some validation.

If the validation passes I then call the following:

```
$("#form).submit();
```

`#form` being the id I have given my form.

In my form tag I have the following to perform the actual posting:

```
<form id="form" action="../../Middleware/Administrator/SoftwareManagement.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" novalidate>
```

For some reason though, PHP isn't seeing the section being posted so the PHP validation is failing as this section does not exist.

Am I missing something or do I need to do something else to make the section post to PHP?

Comment: A div with contenteditable is not a proper input. Therefore it won't be serialized in a form. You either make an input out of it (write to hidden input when validated passes, for example) or send the data yourself (via ajax, not relying on form submission)

Comment: to do that don't use a form at all, get content via DOM and send it via ajax. and redirect after via javascript if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this 
Get that section's text using jquery and store it in a hidden input type=text and submit that form.